# How do I explicitly set available languages in an AIR for iOS app?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, itunes

So we've just published our first AIR app to the iTunes App Store, and to our horror the languages are listed as English, Chinese, Czech, etc. Yeah, it's only English. But we only added an English localization for the app metadata, and for the life of me I can't find anywhere else to explicitly state which languages are available in the app.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official work around to resolve this issue :

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/863281

However it would be nice to hear news that the new air versions support this in the xml config file

Comment: issue resolved by adobe   <supportedLanguages>en</supportedLanguages>